# Identityserver4 and Api Resource in same Asp.net Application

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

If i host my Identityserver4 and the Api in the same Asp.net Application.
What will be used for authentication for the API Controllers?
The Cookie from Identityserver or the token which i get from the oidc-client in my SPA application?

I my tests i can access the API, also if i didn't send the token within the angular http reqeuest as long as i have the Cookie...

But is this a correct and save way???
The MVC Controllers for Identityserver are protected with ValidateAntiforgeryKey, but not the API Controllers.

Does it make sense to host both in the same Application???

**Edit:**
In Details, the API is used for managing the IdentityServer.
CRUD Operations for Clients, Users, Resources,...

For example:
The IdentityServer is reachable at http://localhost:5000
I want build an Angular2 SPA Admin UI which is available at http://localhost:5000/admin

The reason for mentioning ValidateAntiforgeryKey is, because if i only use Cookie Authentication for the CRUD API i should also protect these API'S with ValidateAntiforgerKey, or?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your API and Identity Server are two separate concerns and should be handled as two separate apps. This makes it a lot easier to maintain.

You need to set up an `ApiResource` and a `Client` where you add the `ApiResource` as an `AllowedScope` in your Identity Server configuration.

Then in your API app, you must add add the authentication middleware `UseIdentityServerAuthentication`.

The details are explained here:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html

I can see you are mentioning `ValidateAntiforgeryKey`. This attribute is not used for protecting against unauthorized users, but to make sure form data is being posted from legitimate forms.